# count of multiple column with join not showing proper result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Transactid   dtime       Ecode    DelEcode
1           2013-08-01   E003      null
2           2013-08-01   E003      E003
3           2013-08-02   E001
4           2013-08-02   E001
```

I want to get count of `Ecode` and `DelEcode` with particular date, and name of `Ecode`. Now I am getting answer if the particular `Ecode` having both `Ecode` and `DelEcode`  My stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Driverperformanceforalldriver] @startdate DATETIME,
                                                                 @enddate DATETIME AS BEGIN DECLARE @date1 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @startdate + ' 00:01:00.000', 120);

DECLARE @date2 DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, @enddate + ' 23:23:59.000', 120) ;

 ;

WITH cnt AS
  (SELECT e.ecode,
          Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date,
          e.ename,
          Count(q.ecode) cntEcode
   FROM employeemaster_tbl e
   JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.ecode
   WHERE q.ecode in
       (SELECT e.Ecode
        FROM dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl e
        WHERE e.gid NOT IN
            (SELECT did
             FROM dbo.Designation_tbl d
             WHERE d.Dname ='Driver'))
     AND dtime >=''+ @date1 + ''
     AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + ''
   GROUP BY e.ecode,
            e.ename,
            Cast(q.dtime AS DATE)),
     del AS
  (SELECT e.ecode,
          Cast(q.dtime AS DATE) AS Date,
          e.ename,
          Count(q.delecode) CntDelEcode
   FROM employeemaster_tbl e
   JOIN transaction_tbl q ON e.ecode = q.delecode
   WHERE q.delecode IN
       (SELECT e.Ecode
        FROM dbo.EmployeeMaster_tbl e
        WHERE e.gid NOT IN
            (SELECT did
             FROM dbo.Designation_tbl d
             WHERE d.Dname ='Driver'))
     AND dtime >= '' + @date1 + ''
     AND dtime <= '' + @date2 + ''
   GROUP BY e.ecode,
            e.ename,
            Cast(q.dtime AS DATE))
SELECT del.ecode,
       del.[Date],
       del.ename,
       ISNULL(cnt.cntEcode, 0) CntEcode ,
       ISNULL(del.CntDelEcode, 0) AS CntDelEcode
FROM cnt FULL
JOIN del ON del.ecode = cnt.ecode
AND del.[Date] = cnt.[Date]
AND del.Ename = cnt.Ename
ORDER BY del.date END
```

After executing, I am getting this output:

```
Ecode    dtime       Ename     cntEcode  CntDelCode
E003     2103-08-01  raheem     2        1
null     null        null       2        0
```

If having any `DelEcode` then only it shows the other detils(I meant if having any `E001` in `DelEcode` then work fine. What is wrong with my stored procedure?

```
Ecode    dtime      Ename      cntEcode CntDelCode
E003     2103-08-01  raheem     2        1
E001     2103-08-02  jaseem     2        0
```

Comment: Is your `cnt`  table holding incorrect data? Or something wrong with the `Join`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `select` part of the procedure:

```
SELECT del.ecode,
       del.[Date],
       del.ename,
       ISNULL(cnt.cntEcode, 0) CntEcode ,
       ISNULL(del.CntDelEcode, 0) AS CntDelEcode
FROM cnt FULL JOIN
     del
     ON del.ecode = cnt.ecode AND del.[Date] = cnt.[Date] AND del.Ename = cnt.Ename;
```

You are doing a `full join` and then pulling the data out from only one table.  There may be no data in that table.  So, use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT coalesce(del.ecode, cnt.ecode) as ecode,
       coalesce(del.[Date], cnt.[Date]) as [Date],
       coalesce(del.ename, cnt.Ename) as Ename,
       coalesce(cnt.cntEcode, 0) as CntEcode,
       coalesce(del.CntDelEcode, 0) as CntDelEcode
FROM cnt FULL JOIN
     del
     ON del.ecode = cnt.ecode AND del.[Date] = cnt.[Date] AND del.Ename = cnt.Ename;
```

Comment: yes,sir perfect..now i got exact out put..thanks for helping.i shall be very thank full to you